# Backbone events not working with object.function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to delegate my events through a object. But the event won't fire, if I reference it directly (`"click .formations div":this.movement.leaveCell`) it will throw a JS error

```
events: {
    "click .formations div":"enterCell", //option A
    "click .save ":"movement.leaveCell", //option B
    "click .save ":function(ev){this.movement.leaveCell(ev, this);}, //option C currently works
},
enterCell: function(ev){
    $(ev.currentTarget).addClass('highlight');
},
movement: {
    leaveCell: function(ev){
        $(ev.currentTarget).removeClass('highlight');
    }
},
```

How can I get `option B` to work?

Comment: remove `'this'`, like `"click .formations div":"enterCell"`

Comment: see update :D did it wrong my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Backbone's source you can see that method responsible for events delegating [`delagateEvents`](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-138)

```
delegateEvents: function(events) {
      if (!(events || (events = _.result(this, 'events')))) return this;
      this.undelegateEvents();
      for (var key in events) {
        var method = events[key];
        if (!_.isFunction(method)) method = this[events[key]];
        if (!method) continue;

        var match = key.match(delegateEventSplitter);
        var eventName = match[1], selector = match[2];
        method = _.bind(method, this);
        eventName += '.delegateEvents' + this.cid;
        if (selector === '') {
          this.$el.on(eventName, method);
        } else {
          this.$el.on(eventName, selector, method);
        }
      }
      return this;
    },
```

From here you can see that native implementation of `delegateEvents()` will not handle your case. It will try to search for `movement.leaveCell` which is incorrect.

If you want to force Backbone.View to do it in your way, you should rewrite this method.

---

**Update**

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/vvahans/d9L6Lbwn/20/) is simple working fiddle with rewritten `delegateEvents` method.

```
Backbone.View.prototype.delegateEvents = function(events) {
      if (!(events || (events = _.result(this, 'events')))) return this;
      this.undelegateEvents();
      for (var key in events) {
        var method = events[key];
          if (!_.isFunction(method)) {
          var behaviors = method.split('.');
              if(behaviors.length > 1) {
                  method = this[behaviors[0]][behaviors[1]];
              } else {
                  method = this[events[key]];
              }

          }
        if (!method) continue;

        var match = key.match(/^(\S+)\s*(.*)$/);
        var eventName = match[1], selector = match[2];
        method = _.bind(method, this);
        eventName += '.delegateEvents' + this.cid;
        if (selector === '') {
          this.$el.on(eventName, method);
        } else {
          this.$el.on(eventName, selector, method);
        }
      }
      return this;
    };
```

This example will work for one level deep objects but no more.

I will recommend you to look at [Marionette.js](http://marionettejs.com/) and the [`Marionette.Behaviors`](http://marionettejs.com/docs/marionette.behaviors.html), which is also designed to separate view's and its behaviors.

Comment: Nice one, thanks for looking into this :D I had looked at Marionette but didn't really see the main benifit's other than the event's not stacking across views, which isn't a problem in this current project.